# How to install drivers so sqlsrv_connect works on Centos 7

Tags: php, sql-server, centos7

Is there a straightforward, centos blessed, way to install the drivers so that I can connect to a remote mssql server?  I currently get the following error:

```
Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect
```

I have tried many of the solutions out there but nothing works.  I am running PHP 7.1.6

Comment: Are you trying to connect mssql on centos?

Comment: I am trying to connect to a remove mssql server from a centos server.